# Is it possible to say "I'm in the final stage of doing something?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I've been playing this game where upgrading each building consists of a certain number of stages. Is it possible to say "I'm in the final stage of upgrading... say Stables?"

Comment: Why not? It merely assumes that there is a single final stage as opposed to several final stages. Centenarians, for example, may be said to be in the final stage of life.

Comment: And can you think of any other ways of saying it?